# Morphia cannot map entities

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia, playframework-2.3

Using morphia,java play for a assignment.

I have 2 collections, a department and agent collections. A department has many agents. The department class has a List that has the annotation @Reference.

When I delete an agent and try to fetch the department the agent is in, I received an error as below

org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappingException: Could not map entities.

I added (lazy=true) after @Reference but still does not work.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If you want actual answers I suggest you post at least the relevant entity code and the entire error stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behaviour. You'll need to ensure that you delete references first and only then remove the target document.

Referencing is a concept only enforced by the drivers (for eager / lazy loading) and there's no cascading for it. For the database the reference is a generic field.